# Views in custom view not inflating

Tags: android

I have a volume screen that I want the user to be able to inflate from anywhere in the app.

```
class VolumeScreen @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : RelativeLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

private var audioManager = context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager

fun inflate(context: Context) {

    LayoutInflater
        .from(context)
        .inflate(R.layout.screen_volume, this, true)

    initUI()

}

fun hide() {

    this.visibility = View.GONE

}

private fun initUI() {

    this.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    TTSUtils.getInstance(context).speakText(resources.getString(R.string.volume_help))

    val audioStream = AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM

    var currentVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(audioStream)

    val maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(audioStream)

    volumeLevelText.text = resources.getString(R.string.volume_percentage, currentVolume.times(10).toString())

    increaseButton.setOnClickListener {

        if (currentVolume < 10) {
            currentVolume += 1
        }

        audioManager.setStreamVolume(audioStream, currentVolume, 0)

        volumeLevelText.text = resources.getString(R.string.volume_percentage, currentVolume.times(10).toString())

    }

    decreaseButton.setOnClickListener {

        if (currentVolume > 0) {
            currentVolume -= 1
        }

        audioManager.setStreamVolume(audioStream, currentVolume, 0)


        volumeLevelText.text = resources.getString(R.string.volume_percentage, currentVolume.times(10).toString())

    }
    volumeContinueButton.setOnClickListener {
        this.hide()
    }
}
 }
```

.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="768px"
                    android:layout_height="840px"
                    android:background="@color/main_background">

        <TextView
                android:text="@string/volume"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="78px"
                android:textAppearance="@style/ScreenTitle"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="@string/adjust_volume"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="220px"
                android:textAppearance="@style/ScreenSubtitle"/>


        <TextView
                android:text="@string/volume_percentage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="350px"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Amount"
                android:id="@+id/volumeLevelText"/>


        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                      android:gravity="center_vertical"
                      android:layout_marginBottom="171px"
                      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

            <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/connector_line"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />

            <Button android:layout_width="348px"
                    android:layout_height="104px"
                    android:text="@string/decrease_volume"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/SelectionButtonText"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_background_coral"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_remove_81dp"
                    android:paddingRight="29px"
                    android:paddingLeft="30px"
                    android:id="@+id/decreaseButton"
            />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                      android:gravity="center_vertical"
                      android:layout_marginBottom="171px"
                      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                      android:layout_alignParentRight="true">



            <Button android:layout_width="348px"
                    android:layout_height="104px"
                    android:text="@string/increase_volume"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/SelectionButtonText"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_background_coral"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_add_81px"
                    android:paddingRight="29px"
                    android:paddingLeft="30px"
                    android:id="@+id/increaseButton"
            />

            <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/connector_line"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />


        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                      android:gravity="center_vertical"
                      android:layout_marginBottom="31px"
                      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                      android:layout_alignParentRight="true">



            <Button android:layout_width="348px"
                    android:layout_height="104px"
                    android:text="@string/cont"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/SelectionButtonText"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_background_olive"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:id="@+id/volumeContinueButton"
            />

            <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/connector_line"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />


        </LinearLayout>
```

In activity's .xml:

```
   <group.flowbird.indygotvm.views.VolumeScreen
        android:id="@+id/volumeScreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="80px"
        android:layout_marginBottom="104px"
        android:elevation="1px"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </group.flowbird.indygotvm.views.VolumeScreen>
```

The first time inflate() is called, the views are updated according to the code inside of initUI(). But if it is re-inflated after hide() is called, none of that stuff happens, even though initUI() is called again. How do I make sure the view is being re-rendered or assigned its onClickListener() each time inflate() is called on it?

Comment: Are you sure `inflate` is being called? What does debugging say?

Comment: Yes, in the actual code I have log statements that I removed for clarity. Both inflate() and initUI() are reached.

Comment: And what is the layout inspector showing?

Comment: Layout inspector shows the view with the default value for volume, not the value fetched in initUI with getStreamVolume() and assigned to the volumeLevelText text view. Also the buttons don't work. This is only on inflations after the first.

Comment: I insist that those methods are never called. Put breakpoints and see what is happening.

Comment: Ok so this is strange. Not only is the line that sets the view's text being reached, but the breakpoint indicates that the text property of the TextView (volumeLevelText) contains the correct string. It just shows the default text when the view is actually inflated. Bizarre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This view never is inflated because the init method do nothing.  Try to use the init Kotlin constructor to inflate the view and init the UI:

```
init {
 LayoutInflater
        .from(context)
        .inflate(R.layout.screen_volume, this, true)

    initUI()
}
```

With the previous code, when the activity calls the setContentView method, the views are inflated including your custom view.

Use the constructor context in the inflate() method removing the context param.  But if you don´t need to inflate this view programatically, then is not necessary this method.

Comment: Adding the inflater to the init block and putting initUI() by itself in my inflate() method worked. Thank you!